# How to call a racket procedure from terminal by giving command line argumands

Tags: racket

I have a racket file called foo.rkt Inside that file I have a procedure called textify and it takes 2 parameters. Now how can I call this procedure from terminal ? What I want to do is simply:

```
> racket foo.rkt myfirstarg mysecondarg
```

and then I want this call to activate `(textify myfirstarg mysecondarg)` procedure. Is this possible ?

Here is the content of foo.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require wxme) 
(provide 
 (contract-out 
  [textify (-> path-string? path-string? void?)])) 
(define (textify in out) 
  (call-with-input-file in 
    (λ (in-port) 
      (call-with-output-file out 
        (λ (out-port) 
          (copy-port (wxme-port->text-port in-port) out-port)) 
        #:exists 'truncate))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this as the last expression in your file:

```
(apply textify (vector->list (current-command-line-arguments)))
```

If you are making a more advanced program that has switches you can use [`command-line`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Command-Line_Parsing.html) that does this for you.